# Bootstrap Timepicker set MaxHours dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to update timepicker on some SELECT change action:

```
 $('#StartTime').timepicker({
                    defaultTime: resourceOfficeStartTime,
                    minuteStep: 3,
                    showInputs: false,
                    disableFocus: true,
                    showMeridian: false,
                    maxHours: endHour
                });
```

But it works only one time next time select value change is triggered the maxhours do not change.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- timepicker('remove') in order to remove the plugin
- timepicker({.....}) in order to reinitialize the plugin

```js
function initTimepicker(idSelector, endHour) {
    $(idSelector).timepicker({
        defaultTime: 'current',
        minuteStep: 3,
        showInputs: false,
        disableFocus: true,
        showMeridian: false,
        maxHours: endHour
    });
}
$(function () {
    initTimepicker('#StartTime', 24);
    $('#cmh').on('click', function(e) {
        var endHour = +$('#maxHours').val();
        if (endHour == 0) {
            $('#maxHours').val('1');
            endHour = 1;
        }
        if (endHour > 24) {
            $('#maxHours').val('24');
            endHour = 24;
        }
        // remove
        $('#StartTime').timepicker('remove');
        // reinit
        initTimepicker('#StartTime', endHour);
    })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                <input id="StartTime" type="text" class="form-control input-small">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="maxHours" placeholder="maxHours">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="cmh">Change maxHours</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A different approach can be based on **changeTime.timepicker** event plus a couple of attributes in order to save the custom max hour value and previous hour value. In the following the snippet.

```js
var endHour = 24;
$('#StartTime').attr({'maxHours': endHour, 'prevH': -1}).timepicker({
    defaultTime: 'current',
    minuteStep: 3,
    showInputs: false,
    disableFocus: true,
    showMeridian: false,
    maxHours: endHour
}).on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {
    var maxh = +this.getAttribute('maxhours');
    var prevh = +this.getAttribute('prevH');
    if (e.time === undefined) {
        if (this.value.trim().length != 0) {
            $(this).timepicker('setTime', ('00' + maxh).slice(-2) + ':00');
        }
        return;
    }
    var h = e.time.hours + ((e.time.meridian || '').toUpperCase() == 'PM' ? 12 : 0);
    if (prevh == -1) {
        $(this).attr('prevH', h);
        $(this).timepicker('setTime', e.time.hours +':'+ e.time.minutes);
        return;
    }
    if (h > maxh || (h == maxh && e.time.minutes != 0)) {
        if (prevh == maxh) {
            h = 0;
        } else {
            h = maxh;
        }
        $(this).timepicker('setTime', h +':00');
    }
    $(this).attr('prevH', h);
});

$('#cmh').on('click', function(e) {
    var endHour = +$('#maxHours').val();
    if (endHour == 0) {
        $('#maxHours').val('1');
        endHour = 1;
    }
    if (endHour > 24) {
        $('#maxHours').val('24');
        endHour = 24;
    }
    $('#StartTime').attr('maxHours', endHour).trigger('changeTime.timepicker');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                <input id="StartTime" type="text" class="form-control input-small">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="maxHours" placeholder="maxHours">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="cmh">Change maxHours</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```